# Failing battery or failing motors

Tags: dc

I have a problem with a project I'm working on. I am modifying a nerf gun for my son and running into a issue. I know I'm over powering the stock system with more power. Originally it came with 4C alkaline batters an I have altered it to take a 12v 1.3a security back up battery. Others has upgraded and has ran this same setup with 15 v on 10 AA batteries. My issue is that after about 10 seconds the system acts like the battery is dead. On the charger the battery is charged. After a few hours on the charger I'm back up to about 10 seconds. The motors turn full speed each time as they are fine. Two small batteries shouldn't kill a battery that size that fast. After using and testing the battery is testing fine on the multimeter. And if it is the motors why would they still work after some time of rest. Any guidance is appreciated.

Anthony

Comment: Dead battery. (If it's for security system backup it probably wasn't optimised for running motors)

Comment: If battery is in other than absolutely dead condition you are unlikely to drain it in 10 minutes. 12V x 1.3AH x 3600 = 56000J. In 10 minutes that 56000/(10x60) = 94 Watts. **IF** it is in goor order then 9 Watts is liable to make the motor want to melt and crawl off into a corner. Even at lower power motor may be getting VERY hot and misbehaving.

Comment: This probably counts as abuse of the pack, which depending on its type may be potentially hazardous, so you should discontinue the experiments.   It would however have been useful to report if it was placing the pack on the charger which restored it, or if merely waiting a period of time would cause it to bounce back, as cells subjected to heavy discharge rates sometimes do.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so the stock setup with 4 C batteries runs on 6V but has a capacity of 8,000 mAh because its in series.

Your "security battery" only has 1,300 mAh. This means that it will die far quicker 6.15 times quicker than the stock setup.

The other people with there 10 AA batteries in series have 2,500 mAh of capacity. So their set up should die 3.2 times quicker than the stock setup.

So long story short you need a bigger battery (more capacity). **Dead Battery** Good luck, sounds like a fun project!

[image: Image of batteries in series and parallel]

Comment: Series batteries add voltage, have mAh of SMALLEST mAh cell in series stack, Current capability ~~~= that of smallest battery. | So eg 10 x Alkaline 3,000 mAh AA in series = 10-16V, 3,000 mAh nominal.

Comment: Thanks, @RussellMcMahon for clearing that up! I flip flopped them.